# How can I generate a server AddressSpace from a XML nodeset file?

Tags: node.js, node-opcua

I am getting familiar with the node-opc-ua project and I want to generate a servers address space from a given nodeset (xml file) automatically.

Is there a possibility?

Comment: I've found a function called `generate_address_space(addressSpace, xmlFiles, callback)` in the file _load_nodeset2.js_. Unfortunately there is no documentation about this. Maybe someone has a hint for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify more than one `nodeset2.xml` files to load to enrich the address space. Here is a simplified example.

```
var opcua = require("node-opcua");

var nodeset_filename1 ="CustomAddressSpaceNodeset2.xml";
var nodeset_filename2 ="OtherCustomAddressSpaceNodeset2.xml";

var server_options = {
   /* [...] */
   nodeset_filename: [
     opcua.nodesets.standard_nodeset_file,
     nodeset_filename1,
     nodeset_filename2 
   ]
   /*  other server options here */
};

var server = new opcua.OpcuaServer(server_options);

server.start(function (err) {
});
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my late response!

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this. :)

Comment: Is there a solution for the "regular" https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard ?

Comment: Hello guys, I am trying to use your approach with an Information Model that I created using the SIOME tool. 
I always get an error:
this.bodyXML = this._cloneFragment.value;
Do you know why?

Comment: Andrea, the xml file would require closer investigation, I suggest you contact the author of the node-opcua stack directly.