# How to import nodeset xml file to opc ua server?

Tags: opc, opc-ua, node-set, node-opcua

I'm trying to develop opc ua client. I have node set files (euromap 77 standards) and i want to have test opc server in my computer so i can develop and test my client application.

I have found many opc server demo application but they all simulated with couple of values.  I want to import different nodeset and work on that such as this

http://www.euromap.org/files/Opc_Ua.EUROMAP77.NodeSet2.xml

is there any demo or test opc ua server allows me to import these files ? I'm searching for months but no luck.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41207337/406458

Comment: Thank you so much. yesterday i saw this post just 10 min. ago i was testing and i can confirm its successful.