# Opcua Server: Multiple nodeset.xml files

Tags: c#, opc, opc-ua

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41207337/8096664) for the node.opcua Server(which gets a "server_options" variable offering multiple xml-paths):

Is there a possibility to load multiple nodeset.xml files into a "regular" [Opcua Server](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard)(which gets just one string for the xml-path(and one for the namespace))?

Answer (score 0):

So, finally i made a simple work around: Just extended the UaNodesFile string to a string array and iterate through it at NodeManager. It isn't the cleanest solution, but it works for me.

Comment: Hei,

Would appreciate if you could provide your work-around code?


Also, Are you using licenced version of OPC Ua for .Net or  open source code from github?